# BugSnag not working for Laravel Vapor in production

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, bugsnag, laravel-vapor

I am trying the BugSnag integration with a Laravel app deployed on AWS Lambda through Laravel Vapor.

Bugsnag is working fine on my local but doesn’t send any error from AWS Lamda.

I also tried Bugsnag::setBatchSending(false) but it is still not working for me.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel Vapor changes default logging configuration to the stderr channel, which is captured and logged by AWS CloudWatch.

Adding a new vapor channel using the stack driver that includes both the stderr and BugSnag channels worked for me.

In .env.production

`LOG_CHANNEL=vapor`

In config/logging.php

```
return [

    "channels" => [        

        "vapor" => [
            "driver" => "stack",
            "channels" => ["bugsnag", "stderr"],
            "ignore_exceptions" => false,
        ],

        "bugsnag" => [
            "driver" => "bugsnag",
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: does this work for you on web/cli/queue? We are doing the same with custom cloudwatch logs, yet doesn't work on queue but does on web/cli. Does yours work on all?

Comment: If you set batch settings to false, queue jobs seem to report to Bugsnag. Set BUGSNAG_BATCH_SENDING=false in your environment.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work correctly for me in queued jobs, only for web requests.

Taylor commented on twitter that it's best to do this in your application's error handler (`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`)

```php
public function report(Throwable $e)
{
    if (app()->environment() !== 'local') {
        Bugsnag::notifyException($e);
        Bugsnag::flush();
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

This way, exceptions are correctly reported in web, cli and queue.